# Negative mass from double integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

So I am trying to find the mass of this rod which is a parallelogram. The link to the depiction of the rod is provided here: [Desmos graph of rod](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z1isd6g4tm). The mass of the rod given a density function $\rho (x,y)$, would be provided by :

$$\int_{y = -r\cos (\theta)}^{y = 0}\int_{x = -\tan (\theta)y}^{x = -\tan (\theta)y + s} \rho (x,y) dx dy$$

Where *r* is the length of the rod, $\theta$ is the angle from the vertical axis (the y-axis), and *s* is the width of the rod. I defined my coordinates such that downward is negative.

Let's say that *r* = 7, $\theta$ = $\frac{\pi }{6}$, and s = 2. Let's also say that, for some reason, the density function is defined as $\rho (x,y) = sin(x)cos(y)$. If you evaluate the double integral, you would get a negative result. What does that mean in this case? The mass cannot be negative.

Answer (score 2):

No, a mass cannot be negative. But a density function cannot take negative values either.

Comment: Oh yeah, I almost forgot that. So I should change my coordinate system so that downard is positive?

Comment: I can't answer that question. It's your question, not mine.

Comment: I believe I know the answer, I just wanted to check to make sure if I was right. I will continue the problem with my suggestion.